# addClass() in jquery is not working on video tag

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add a class in a `<video>` tag. But it is odd that the class isn't adding. I know that this would work on other machine, but not for mine. Is there any reason why this isn't working? Please see my code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('video').addClass('glow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video class="reponsive" src="..." height="400" width="600"></video>
```

Comment: i just put your code in snippet and works just fine.

Comment: check the console for any errors - could be a js conflict

Answer (score 0):

Your `glow` class is indeed getting added with your above code.

You can confirm this by checking the the element has the class with **[`$('video').hasClass('glow')`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($('video').hasClass('glow'));
  $('video').addClass('glow');
  console.log($('video').hasClass('glow'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video class="reponsive" src="..." height="400" width="600"></video>
```

If you are not seeing the same result, then there is likely a JavaScript conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Is your video being dynamically added after the page has loaded? If so, I've used this method with success. Comments added to explain.

```
//this is the same as a document ready function, but less typing
$(function() {
  //naming interval for later use, and setting that interval
  var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
    //add class glow to video tag(s)
    $('video').addClass('glow');
    //check if any video tag has class glow
    if($('video').hasClass('glow')) {
      //if it does, clear the interval so it stops running
      clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
  //4 milliseconds is the shortest interval available as of today
  },4);  
});
```